# Catch commit exception in Spring jms listener

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I'm using Spring @JmsListener to consume message from IBM MQ queue (running in Docker container). I test a scenario as below:

1. Send message to MQ via web browser
2. My Spring service will consume and send extracted data from message to a stub (wiremock)
3. service receives success response and exit normally

In a happy case, message will be committed and removed from the queue, now I add response delay in stub (30s for example), when service waiting for response, I quit Docker to simulate a network issue or MQ down (docker stop cause MQ quiescing which is not my expectation).

So I have 2 questions here?

1. How can I catch the commit exception thrown by DefaultMessageListenerContainer?
2. I use DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory::setExceptionListener() method to attach a listener, I can log the exception here but logback MDC is not logged (MDC contains messageId and payload for audit purpose). How can I pass MDC values to this listener?

Source code:

```
@Bean
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory containerFactory() {
  DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
  factory.setConnectionFactory(createConnectionFactory());
  factory.setExceptionListener(exceptionListener());
  factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(javax.jms.Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
  return factory;
}

@Bean
public ExceptionListener exceptionListener() {
  return exception -> {
    if (exception.getCause() instanceof InterruptedException) {
      // MDC value is not logged in below log.error()
      log.error("commit error");
    } else {
      log.error("jms connection error");
    }
  }
}

---

@JmsListener(id="0", destination="DEV.QUEUE.1", containerFactory="containerFactory")
public void listener(Message msg) {
  try {
    // extract data
    MDC.put("key", value); // for audit
    // call stub
  } catch (JMSException e) {
    throw new Exception(e); // throw exception, don't commit
  }
}
```

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: I don't see any code that sets up a transaction, or a delay between message fetch and commit, or a a commit.

Comment: @daury if you run ``docker stop`` on the MQ queue manager docker instance then your queue manager will stop. If you terminate the process then it will terminate. Can you use ``docker network disconnect`` to simulate a network outage between your various containers?
Do you see the ``JMSXDeliveryCount`` incremented for the message you are processing?

Comment: @chughts I don't set up transaction here, if listener return normally without exception, message is committed and removed from queue, otherwise it will be moved to a DLQ - this behavior is configured in IBM MQ.

Comment: @richc `JMSXDeliveryCount` is 1 when I receive msg and after I disconnect, it's still 1, but there is no exception thrown from my service when I run `docker network disconnect`

Comment: When I run `dis qs(DEV.QUEUE.1)` it returns UNCOM(1), but after a while, it returns UNCOM(NO)

Answer (score 0):

1. I can catch the JMSException in the error handler

```
@Bean
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory containerFactory() {
  ...
  factory.setErrorHandler(errorHandler());
}

@Bean
public ErrorHandler errorHandler() {
  return exception -> {
    if (exception.getMessage().contains("session has already been closed")) {
      // log something here
    }
  }
}
```

2. There is a MDC.clear() in my listener method so that's why I lost MDC fields. Remove it solves the issue.